# How to have two different environments using docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a app inside docker-compose:

```
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.${ENV}
    container_name: "whatsnxt-${ENV}"
    image: "whatsnxt:${ENV}-v4.31"
    env_file:
      - .env.${ENV}
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
```

And based on the `${ENV}`, I was able to create env specific image and containers on ec2 like:

```
whatsnxt-prod-vx.xx
whatsnxt-dev-vx.xx
```

Now, my second container `dev` is unable to talk to ec2 classic load balancer on port 443 as `prod` container is already bind to that port

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is using `classic load balancer` a hard requirement? As you already see, you cannot reuse port 443 to another target. You can switch to ALB and use `Host-based routing`. E.g.: Rules `dev.whatsnxt.com` to dev target group and  `prod.whatsnxt.com` to prod target group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use environment files.

Change your compose file to

```
    ports:
      - ${NODE_PORT:-4444}:4444
```

Then create a development environment file called `.env.dev` containing

```
NODE_PORT=4443
```

Then when you bring up your development system, do

```
docker compose --env-file .env.dev up
```

and your development system should be available on port 4443.

If you don't specify an environment file with a NODE_PORT value, port 4444 will be used as the default.